# How to upload large amount of data from Angular 4, node and SQL Server 2016

Tags: node.js, angular, sql-server-2016

Currently, I have a data grid from which user inputs some data and data is having paging also, user is selecting in million and send for update.

How can I send large amount of Data from angular 4 app using node API and SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Perhaps a [table-valued parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#table-valued-parameter-tvp)

Comment: Currently I am using only this